# IndexError when attempting to reference list during sort

Tags: python, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception, python-2.x

This is a bit of a strange bug in Python:

```
l1 = ['a', 'ab', 'cc', 'bc']
l1.sort(key=lambda x: zip(*l1)[0].count(x[0]))
```

The intent of this snippet is to sort elements by the frequency of their first letter. However, this produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Computing the keys separately does not give me an error, however:

```
sortkeys = [zip(*l1)[0].count(x[0]) for x in l1]
```

Where is this `IndexError` coming from? Surely, `zip(*l1)[0]` is not empty (it is equal to `('a', 'a', 'c', 'b')`), and `x[0]` cannot be empty because all list elements are non-empty...so what's going on?

EDIT: I'm well aware this is not an ideal way to sort a list. I'm curious *why* this happens, not in what I should write.

Comment: creating `sortkeys` like this results in `TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable` on Python 3.4. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pavel - The OP is using Python 2.x, in which `zip` returns a list.

Comment: @DSM: I see the duplicates. OK, great, marked (my own question) as a duplicate :P

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen anyone mark _their own_ question as a dupe... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can investigate this to witness the list is indeed empty while it's being sorted in place. 
In fact - that's very good programming imho - because it produces errors to programmers forgetting that it is sorted in place instead of producing bugs that are very hard to figure out later.

Try this:

```
l1 = ['a', 'ab', 'cc', 'bc']

def y(x):
    print l1
    return zip(*l1)[0].count(x[0])
y('cc')
l1.sort(key = y)
```

the output would be:

```
['a', 'ab', 'cc', 'bc']
[]
```

(and then the exception)